# Efficient way to produce facetted bar plots

Tags: r, ggplot2, tidyverse

Is there a way to produce facetted bar plots as rapidly as you can produce facetted box plots?

For instance this code will produce box plots facetted by a grouping variable:

```
library(tidyverse)

mtcars %>% 
  ggplot(aes(x = am, y = mpg)) + 
  geom_boxplot() + 
  facet_grid(~ cyl)
```

But the "same" code for a bar plot fails because `geom_col()` expects to have means provided, which would take considerably more time to calculate:

```
mtcars %>% 
  ggplot(aes(x = am, y = mpg)) + 
  geom_col() + 
  facet_grid(~ cyl)
```

If there is a way to produce facetted bar plots at the speed of facetted box plots, I'd love to hear your methods.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand your question. for a boxplot, one has to calculate several location parameters, Why should calculating just the mean be slower?

Comment: What do you mean when you say the bar plot code "fails"? It seems to work fine for me. Also, if there is a real speed issue that you are running into because of the size of your data (a speed issue that actually hinders you from achieving your goals), you should try to come up with some example code that demonstrates that issue.

Comment: @Marius, I say the code fails because it produces a meaningless plot. The y-values of the bars do not represent the means of the x-variable levels, instead they represent the summation of the x-variable levels mpg values, which is not useful.

Comment: Hi @lukeA, I don't see why parameters need to be calculated for the box plots (my 4 lines of code created boxplots without first calculating parameters). But to successfully create bar plots I need to calculate a table of means and SEs, which are then plotted with `geom_col`. In exploratory data analysis, this extra time to create the table adds up, and since box plots can be created without first creating tables, I wanted to see if bar plots could also be created without first generating tables.

Comment: It's going to add up whether you compute it or ggplot2 computes it under the covers. You might want to try Tableau if typing is an issue for you. Also, perhaps `stat_summary(fun.y="mean", geom="col")`

Comment: @Joe Ah you mean "speed" in terms of lines of code, not in terms of processing time. (I was confused because when talking about R & efficiency, it's mostly about R beeing slowish for certain tasks compared to other programming languages.) Anyway, hrbrmstr's solution should do the trick, does it?

Answer (score 1):

There seems to be no notable difference between those two plots

```
library(tidyverse)

box_plot <- function() mtcars %>% 
  ggplot(aes(x = am, y = mpg)) + 
  geom_boxplot() + 
  facet_grid(~ cyl)

bar_plot <- function() mtcars %>% 
  ggplot(aes(x = am, y = mpg)) + 
  geom_col() + 
  facet_grid(~ cyl)

library(microbenchmark)

mb <- microbenchmark(box_plot(), bar_plot())

mb
# Unit: milliseconds
#        expr      min       lq     mean   median       uq      max neval cld
#  box_plot() 2.412589 2.431660 2.538586 2.475522 2.534515 9.966422  1000   a 
#  bar_plot() 2.543288 2.566173 2.670544 2.609146 2.671571 5.254653  1000   b

autoplot(mb)
```

[image]

A similar test with the full diamonds dataset yields the same result. I think the bottleneck is the graphical device that needs a lot of time to display a ggplot object.

```
box_p <- box_plot()
bar_p <- bar_plot()

# !!! this will need about 2 minutes to execute !!!
mb2 <- microbenchmark(plot(box_p), plot(bar_p), times = 100)

mb2
# Unit: milliseconds
#         expr      min       lq     mean   median       uq      max neval cld
#  plot(box_p) 405.0375 513.7360 532.1827 524.1259 536.8206 740.7494   100   b
#  plot(bar_p) 454.6047 469.3411 489.3676 479.3709 497.9246 717.7909   100  a 

autoplot(mb2)
```

[image]

Comment: Hello @Gregor de Cillia, thank you for such a detailed response, but my question was not regarding the milliseconds to create the plots, but that geom_col() is producing the wrong y-values unless I first create a table of means and SEs for it to plot. If you look at the y-values for the geom_col() output you'll see bars claiming ~200 mpg, an impossible value. By contrast geom_boxplot can produce accurate box plots without taking the time to create a separate table of values of plot. I was wondering if geom_col() could be similarly used.

Comment: Something has to "take the time". Why so reticent to actually program?

Answer (score 0):

Thank you to @hrbrmstr for your suggestion to use `stat_summary()`. That was the perfect solution.

```
mtcars %>% 
  ggplot(aes(x = as.factor(am), y = mpg)) + 
  stat_summary(fun.y = "mean", geom = "col") + 
  facet_grid(~ cyl)
```

[image: facetted bar plot]